# Proper Orthogonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove that, for any $\theta$, $\lambda$, $\mu$
>
> $Q = \pmatrix{\cos{\lambda}\cos{\mu} -
>  \cos{\theta}\sin{\lambda}\sin{\mu}&\sin{\lambda}\cos{\mu} +
>  \cos{\theta}\cos{\lambda}\sin{\mu}&\sin{\theta}\sin{\mu}\\-\cos{\lambda}\sin{\mu}
>  - \cos{\theta}\sin{\lambda}\cos{\mu}&-\sin{\lambda}\sin{\mu} + \cos{\theta}\cos{\lambda}\cos{\mu}&\sin{\theta}\cos{\mu}\\ \sin{\theta}\sin{\lambda}&-\sin{\theta}\cos{\lambda}&\cos{\theta}}$
>
> is a proper orthogonal matrix and write down a formula for $Q^{-1}$

How will I be able to do this problem? I know that in order to be a proper orthogonal matrix it must have $\det(Q) = 1$ and it must form orthonormal columns, but how can I show that here?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.or/wiki/Euler_angles   This is associated with Euler angles and represents rotations about some combination of axes.  That's the key to proof

Comment: @Ganesh the book didn't mention anything about euler angles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just calculate $Q Q^T$ and simplify it to $I$, taking into account the trigonometric identities $\cos^2 \alpha + \sin^2 \alpha = 1$.  It's a bit tedious, but has to work if your matrix is correct.

Comment: That was what I was afraid of. I was hoping there was an easier way. Toda Raba!!

Comment: Actually the $(1,3)$ element of your matrix is wrong: $\sin \lambda\; \sin \mu$ should be $\sin\theta\; \sin \mu$.

Comment: Yup, you are right. Thanks for catching that. I edited it.